# Robust way to build a DWH without downtime

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse

I have a process that build a data warehouse using Postgres. The process runs every day at midnight and works in three steps:

- Copy the production database (prod) to a temporary database (dwh_tmp) using pg_dump
- Generate the fact and dimension tables in the temporary schema using the data from the production database
- Rename the current DWH database (dwh -> dwh_old) and move in the temporary database instead (dwh_tmp -> dwh) using `ALTER DATABASE dwh_tmp RENAME TO dwh`

The problem is that the last step fails if there are still open connections to the dwh database. To get rid of these connections (e.g. using `pg_terminate_backend()`) I would need to run the DWH generation process with super-user privileges, which I'd like to avoid for security reasons.

Any suggestions on how to implement this in a more robust way? My main goal is to make sure that the DWH is always in a good state and the downtime is as small as possible, hence my idea of first building a temporary DWH and then renaming it. I'm not in direct control of the connecting processes that keep me from renaming the database (as they're openend from a different host).

Comment: Why don't you keep using the same DW and use time and date dimensions to 'historize' data. Thus, u well be able to visulize ur current and old DW views. Use a staging area to treat your input data.

Comment: You mean use a temporary schema in the same database? Good idea, will try that!

Comment: Why are you dropping and re-creating your whole warehouse, rather than updating it in-place?  I can see it being *simpler*, but given that 99% of data will be unchanged from day 1 to day 2, surely the performance would be much better to update tables with MERGE statements.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's the solution that I came up with:

- Create a new schema `dwh`
- Build the new version of the DWH in that shema
- Drop the old `public` schema
- Rename the new `dwh` schema to `public`

(this assumes that your main schema is named `public`, of course)

This method works quite reliably and without interrupting/killing existing database connections, so I prefer the solution over my initial "create and rename database" approach. Here's the SQL that I use for building the DWH (it assumes that you're connected to the DWH database):

```
--we drop the temporary schema if it already exists
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS dwh CASCADE;
--we create the temporary schema
CREATE SCHEMA dwh;

--we modify the search path for this session
SET search_path to dwh;

--create your DWH here...

--now we commit the new version

--make sure you're connected to the correct database when executing this ;)
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS public CASCADE;

--we rename the DWH schema to public
ALTER SCHEMA dwh RENAME TO public;

--you might need to restore permissions on the new public schema...
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO dwh_user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO dwh_user;
```

Apart from needing to manually restore permissions and having to recreate extensions in the new schema, I found this solution to be quite optimal as it does not require superuser privileges for the DWH user, and works without creating/dropping any databases. I have not yet figured out a way to copy permissions from one schema to another, which is my only minor issue with this approach.